# How to convert a single code line with multiple operations into a SD?

Tags: database-design, uml, sequence-diagram

Take for example this code line:

`event = eC.getEventRegistry.getEventByTitle((ListView.getSelectionModel.getselectedItem));`

`event` is an instance of `Event`. `eC` is an istance of `ExhibitionCentre`, `getEventByTitle` is an operation from `EventRegistry` which is what is called in `getEventRegistry()`.

I find it hard to translate this or any long line of code into a sequence diagram. Not to mention the multiple operation parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chain of method invocations are no different to if you were calling those objects as seperate variables, so eC.getEventRegistry().getEventByTitle(...) is no different to eC.getEventRegistry() and then [return of getEventRegistry()].getEventByTitle(...) on two separate lines of code. So, your sequence chart might look something like the following:

[image]

Of course, you also have ListView.getSellectionModel.getsellectedItem in there as well but I have left these off for brevity -- the principle is the same.

Comment: thank you so much! but what about the parameters? like `getEventByTitle((ListView.getSellectionModel.getsellectedItem))`

Comment: That is what I assumed was a string type in the getEventByTitle () operation. You would obviously need to call into ListView.getSellectionModel and then [return of that].getSellectedItem to get this.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence in which operations are evaluated is dependent on the compiler you use. A general statement can not be made. As a rule of thumb (which needs to be verified by looking into the compiler specification) you can take this:

- dot separation will be evaluated left to right,
- operation parameters need to be evaluated before the operation can commence,
- instance references will lead to messages sent to the instance to return whatever operation/attribute follows.

Eg. the following operations `A(B()).C()` would first issue `B()` to be evaluated and the result passed to `A()` as parameter. The result of that operation is a dynamic instance (again depending on the compiler) of a certain type which can be shown as a new life line e.g. as `resultOfCall:TheClass` as to where you send the message `C()`.